# Apache Camel - UriEndpoint is missing values for attributes title,syntax

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

After upgrade of JBoss Fuse 6.1 -> 6.2 and as a result Apache Camel 2.12 -> 2.15, the following compilation error occurred in one of our custom components:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] [redacted].java:[11] error: annotation UriEndpoint is missing values for attributes title,syntax
[ERROR] [redacted].java:[8] error: annotation UriEndpoint is missing values for attributes title,syntax
[INFO] 2 errors
```

*-note that the `[redacted]` means "removed" or "anonymized" part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change from:

```
@UriEndpoint(scheme = "[redacted]")
```

to:

```
@UriEndpoint(scheme = "[redacted]", syntax = "scheme:host:port/path", title = "[redacted]")
```

More information in `@UriEndpoint` [JavaDoc](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/tooling/spi-annotations/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spi/UriEndpoint.java)

[The documentation](http://camel.apache.org/endpoint-annotations.html) is quite enigmatic ATM.